# Is possible to create a newglossarystyle with tabularray? or from scratch?

Tags: tables, glossaries, tabularray

I want to recreate this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269565/glossaries-how-to-customize-list-of-symbols-with-additional-column-for-units/269571#269571) but with `tabularray`. As said in documentation

> A style may inherit from an existing style by starting 〈definitions〉with \setglossary-style and then just redefine the commands that are different from the inherited style.

I don't like the longtable style but when I try to change the environment to `longtblr` from `tabularray`, it doesn't work saying tab characters are misplaced.

Is it even possible, since there are predefined styles?

### MWE

```tex
\documentclass{article}                           
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{Symbolslist}

\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}
\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{symb:Pi}{name=\ensuremath{\pi},
    description={Geometrical value},
    unit={},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossaryentry{height}{name=\ensuremath{h},
    description={Height of tower},
    unit={\unit{\m}},
    type=symbolslist}

\newglossarystyle{symbolunittable}{
    \setglossarystyle{long3colheader}
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}{
        \begin{longtblr}{
            p{2cm} p{5cm} p{2cm}
        }
    }
    {
        \end{longtblr}
    }

    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{
        \bfseries Símbolo & \bfseries Descripción & \bfseries Unidades \\ \hline\endhead
    }
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{
        \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}
            & \glossentrydesc{##1}
            & \glsunit{##1}\\
    }
    \ifglsnogroupskip
        \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
    \else
        \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[type=symbolslist,style=symbolunittable]
\end{document}
```

Please see: [How to use DTLforeach (datatool) within a tabularray table?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638066/how-to-use-dtlforeach-datatool-within-a-tabularray-table)

Comment: [Related but unanswered](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/678834/106162), problem appears to be expanding the glossary contents sufficiently.  What do you hope to gain from using `longtblr` over `longtable`?

Comment: Customization and longtable is showing weird outputs (blank rows with no reason to be).

Comment: The blank rows wouldn't be between different starting letters or the name would they?

Comment: @DaiBowen thanks, I just saw redefining `glsgroupskip` solves the problem